# ASP.Net ViewState doesn't work when Control become Enable=False

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0, c#-2.0, viewstate

Why when a control does contain value but it's set to .Enable=False that all controls become disable (that's ok) but why that the ViewState doesn't retain the data on the next post back? If I get the UserControl without modifing its Enable state, the ViewState work between post back.

How can we disable a UserControl that all its control become disable (this part work) but all of them KEEP use the ViewState (this doesn't work)?

### Clarification:

1)In the aspx.cs click button EDIT:

```
myControl.Enabled = false;
//This produce to have all controls in myControl to be disabled.
```

2)In the asp.cs: click Save to leave the EDIT state:

```
myControl.Enabled = true;
//This produce that all controls inside myControl are blank : no viewstate!
```

Other postback works because we do not put myControl.Enable to false.

Comment: I'm unclear here as to what exactly you are asking. Are the controls coming back re-enabled after postback or are they remaining disabled and losing their state? Can you post sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying `.Enable=False` is like a server-side disable, NOT a client-side disable. This is for security purposes so you can truly disable an input element even if the user uses some client-side trickery to "re-enable" it. If you want to perform a client-side disabling, you'll need to use script for that, or perhaps use a `readonly` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Page.Form.SubmitDisabledControls = true;

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, if you want the control to use ViewState and still be disabled, then you have disable the control on the ClientSide.  I use the Page.ClientScript to handle this and register your javascript to disable the control.