# Viewstate not working certain cases when Control Enable=false TextBox looses value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

I found an issue in some of my code and can't figure out the reason why. I'm using *.Net 4.5.*  Can anyone please tell me the difference between these two cases? I tried a few different things such javascript to disable via `Page.ClientScript` or on the body onload event but I'm not getting what I want (TextBox2 is "" and TextBox1 is "Hello, TextBox1"). When I comment out `tmp.Enable = false` everything is fine. I'd like to be able to disable both controls but still access the Text value.  Works fine for "TextBox1" but not "tmp" aka "TextBox2".

The reason for !IsPostBack and TextBox2 being created during the Page_Load is because I'm dynamically creating X number of controls and setting their value from a datareader. they can then be modified by the user and saved to the table. There must be a way!

This post sounds like my problem but I'm getting different results than them.
[ASP.Net ViewState doesn't work when Control become Enable=False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914527/asp-net-viewstate-doesnt-work-when-control-become-enable-false)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function t() {
        document.getElementById("TextBox1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("TextBox2").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" OnClick="button1_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) { TextBox1.Text = "Hello, TextBox1"; }
        TextBox1.Enabled = false; 
        TextBox tmp = new TextBox();
        tmp.ID = "TextBox2";
        if (!IsPostBack) { tmp.Text = "Hello, TextBox2"; }
        tmp.Enabled = false;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tmp); 
    }

    protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tmp = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox2"));
        if(tmp != null)
        {
            tmp.Text.ToString();
        }
        TextBox1.Text.ToString(); 
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
Per haraman's suggestion I was able to get it working by making the following changes:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tmp = new TextBox();
        tmp.ID = "TextBox2";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tmp); 
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) { TextBox1.Text = "Hello, TextBox1"; }
        TextBox1.Enabled = false;

        if (!IsPostBack) { ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text = "Hello, TextBox2"; }
        ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox2")).Enabled = false;


    }
    protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tmp = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox2"));
        if (tmp != null)
        {
            tmp.Text.ToString();
        }
        TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: review your code in button1_click, you are using `tmp.Text.ToString();` and `TextBox1.Text.ToString();`. Where are you using these values? These must be in a statement format i.e. either assign them to a variable or control value.

Comment: This was just for demonstration purposes. In the button click tmp.Text.ToString() returns "" and TextBox1.Text.ToString() returns "Hello, TextBox1". In my example I'm not actually "using" the values, it was just to show the results via the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `ReadOnly = true` instead of `Enabled = false`.

Values for **disabled** form elements are **NOT** passed to the processor method. For more specific details refer [disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/](https://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/)

**EDIT:** *Addition with regard to your code*
Created a test case with your code and found that I just misread your code. Here is what is happening in your code:

1. You create a new TextBox (tmp) on every PostBack.
   **tmp is recreated** (But TextBox1 is already there and NOT recreated)
2. You do NOT assign value to tmp on every PostBack
   **This means there is no text in tmp** (TextBox1 NOT being recreated, retains its text)

More specific details can be found in the [answer given by R.C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17589598/5104101) in this SO post [dynamically-created-controls-losing-data-after-postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589268/dynamically-created-controls-losing-data-after-postback)

A practical approach to the same can be found in this post [ASPNet-Dynamic-Controls-ViewState-Retain-state-for-dynamically-created-controls-on-PostBack](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Dynamic-Controls-ViewState-Retain-state-for-dynamically-created-controls-on-PostBack.aspx)

Comment: why is the value of TextBox1 accessible then?

Comment: The article you linked doesn't talk about asp.net's Enable.  My question was in regards to that and not html disable vs read only.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you sir! :) I was looking at that last night and thought that was the problem but I couldn't figure it out.  Works as expected now.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try using [`Read Only`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) Property????

Read Only

> In the context of a TextBox, readonly allows the user to set focus to
>   and select and copy the text but not modify it. A disabled TextBox
>   does not allow any interaction whatsoever.
>
> Use ReadOnly when you have data that you want the user to see and
>   copy, but not modify. Use a disabled textbox, when the data you are
>   displaying is not applicable in for the current state of a dialog or
>   window.

Enabled:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control can respond to
>   user interaction.

Comment: I think read only will achieve what I'm going for.. However, I was wondering why TextBox1's value is returned when enable=false but TextBox2's value is ""

Comment: Read Only was going to be a little more effort just because in my actual code I have a jQuery datepicker attached to the textbox.  So the contents are "editable" by the user because of that.  Enable = false was just easier and achieves what I wanted. Only when the textbox isn't created/added during the page load however.